# Click event doesn't work inside jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-ui-dialog

got a problem that I have a form page which I open with jQuery UI dialog help. But in this page I have need to use .click event on some objects, but it doesn't work.
The code for this case is simple alert() test from that page.

```
<input type='text' class='input_date' value='' readonly />
```

So I want to get alert when I click on input field inside that dialog form.

```
$('.input_date').click(function() {
    alert('hi')
});
```

What's the problem, how can I get this work? Thanks

Comment: Put your scripts just before `</body>` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you don't have the object you want to bind the event to at the moment of the jquery execution.

You need to `delegate` the event binding in a parent container or use the `getScript` jquery method after your dialog is loaded.

```
<div id="dialogContainer" />

$('#dialogContainer').on('click', '.input_date', function(){
   alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dialog html is generated dynamically, your click callback wont be attached to the ".input_date" elment. Use this instead:

```
$('.input_date').live('click',function() {
    alert('hi')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options inside document.ready   :

```
$(".input_date").keyup(function(){
 alert('hi');
});
```

or

```
$(".input_date").change(function(){
   alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your click event in the open callback, like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
       $('.input_date').click(function(){
          alert("hi!");
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine you just need to set attribute to readonly like
 this:

```
<input type='text' class='input_date' value='' readonly="readonly">




         $('.input_date').click(function () {

              alert('hello');
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given document ready function from jquery. You can do it by

```
$(function() {
// your code
});
```

Sample for your program

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".input_date").bind("click", function(){
alert("hi");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' class='input_date' value='' readonly />
</body>
</html>
```